Displaylink not working on kernel 6.11 (Ubuntu 24.10)
I just updated my main machine to Kubuntu 24.10 (kernel 6.11).
The upgrade did not go perfectly smooth (mainly due to the Plasma session crashing during the process), but it seems to have gone through.
My problem is that the displaylink driver does not seem to work.
sudo apt install displaylink-driver

displaylink-driver is already the newest version (6.1.0-17).
I can not find release notes for version 6.1 of the driver to check if the kernel is supported or not. Anyone had luck with displaylink on 24.10?

I just upgraded smoothly to 24.10 (from 24.04), but DisplayLink didn't work after reboot.  I found this post on the DisplayLink forum.  The OP on that post got it to work by installing evdi-dkms and then using the standalone DisplayLink installer from the Ubuntu Driver Download page (under Latest Official Driver).
This worked for me.  I'll go back in while and retry from the APT repository, after 24.10 has been out for a bit longer.

In the meantime it works from the apt repository too

Cool, I'll go back and give that a try
